# Ssh login hook?

Tags: ssh, hook

Is there a way to run a script/command every time a user connects using ssh? Can it be configured globally (i.e run the script when **any** user login)?

I came across this question on Identica, but there is no answer yet and would like to know it anyway.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For all users, or a particular user? For a single user, set it in their `.bashrc` file; for all users, check out [pam_exec](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_exec.html).

If the users are coming in from `sshd`, you'll want to add the following line to `/etc/pam.d/sshd`; other files depending on their source:

```
session optional pam_exec.so seteuid  /path/to/my/hook.sh
```

For testing purposes, the module is included as `optional`, so that you can still log in if it fails. After you made sure that it works, you can change `optional` to `required`. Then login won't be possible unless the execution of your hook script is successful.

**Note:** As always when you change the login configuration, leave a backup shell open in the background and test the login from a new terminal.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. Can you elaborate a bit more? I'm unfamiliar with this.

Comment: I suppose that I should add `session include pam_exec.so seteuid /path/to/script` to the file `/etc/pam.d/system-remote-login`. Is that correct?

Comment: Either `system-remote-login` or `sshd`, depending on how the user is coming in.

Comment: Awesome! It would be great if you edit the answer to include the information (you know, for others who search for it).

Comment: Note to people googling, you can also put this line `auth optional pam_exec.so  /path/to/my/hook.sh` in `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` to have PAM notify you of ANY authentication events that occur.  This program can also send you push notifications: https://github.com/benjojo/PushAlotAuth

Comment: Note to people searching for this in 2023: PushAlot is as dead as Windows 8/Phone. Nowadays I’d recommend using `kdeconnect`, which supports generally passing notifications between systems. (The tool is not exclusive to KDE either. There are Gnome-based clients.)

Answer (score 8):

there's another way which only influences users using ssh not local ones (which might be better in emergency situations)

see the snippets from the ssh man page below.

in this case the users can usually modify the files themselves (a bit like .bashrc)

> ```
>  ~/.ssh/rc
>          Commands in this file are executed by ssh when the user logs in, just before the user's shell (or command) is started.  See the sshd(8) manual page for more information.
> ```

and this is global and not modifiable by the normal user

> ```
>  /etc/sshrc
>          Commands in this file are executed by ssh when the user logs in, just before the user's shell (or command) is started.  See the sshd(8) manual page for more information.
> ```

Comment: But /etc/sshrc will be executed only if user do not have own ~/.ssh/rc, so this user can bypass

Comment: @isevcik, that is only if PermitUserRC is set to "yes" in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (see `man sshd_config` for details)