# SSH Login Alert Using pam_exec

Tags: ssh, email

Hi I have been trying to follow the information about pam_exec from here:
[Ssh login hook?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7390/ssh-login-hook)

When a user log's in they get:

```
/etc/pam.d/email-alert.sh failed: exit code 8
```

My sshd file has this at the end:

```
session optional pam_exec.so debug seteuid /etc/pam.d/email-alert.sh
```

My email-alert.sh script has this,

```
echo 'ALERT - Remote SSH Shell Access (SERVERNAME) on:' `date` `who` | 
mail -s "Alert: Remote SSH Access from `who | 
cut -d'(' -f2 | cut -d')' -f1`" MYEMAIL@MYEMAIL.com
```

I have tested the script on its own and it emails me no problem.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated as I've been scratching me brain's out trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

First, shell scripts will return the exit status of the last command. One of the commands you're using is exiting with status `8`. Second, `pam_exec` won't have the same environment as you do. So when run manually won't necessarily act the way it would when run as part of the pam stack (which you're experiencing).

`pam_exec` has several built in environment variables that will help you here. I would rewrite the script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
SUBJ="Alert - Remote SSH access from ${PAM_USER}"

mail -s $SUBJ << __MESSAGE__
ALERT - Remote SSH Shell Access (${HOSTNAME}) on $(date)

User ${PAM_USER} logged in from ${PAM_RHOST}

$(who)
__MESSAGE__
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and input, I tried doing as you suggested and the error did disappear, but I do not get an email. I also do not get a email if I manually run the script. Does it matter that I have been using ssmtp? I checked and mail is installed by default. Thanks.

Comment: You should probably check your syslog to see what the error is.