# Send email if user accesses the server via ssh

Tags: ssh, login, profile

I want to get notified if any person accesses my Debian server via ssh.

So I want to send an email whenever a user logs in on my server via ssh, so I added this line at the end of `/etc/profile`:

```
/usr/local/bin/shell-login.sh | mailx -s "SSH Login User $(whoami) on YOUR-HOSTNAME" your@email.org
```

`/usr/local/bin/shell-login.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Login on $(hostname) at $(date +%Y-%m-%d +%H:%M)"
echo "User: "$(whoami)
echo
id
echo
finger
```

This works too well: I get an email every minute now telling me that `root` is logging in, which seems to be caused by `cron` (see `/var/log/auth.log`)

How do I have to change this setup to send no emails on automated internal ssh-calls?

Comment: You can put a check in your bash script for external user by checking the output of `w` and do invert match for the external connection. your bash script should return fail and then do not execute the email alert. let me know if this make sense then I will propose detail answer

Comment: How do you make login in call this script? Do you included it in `/etc/bash.bashrc`? Something in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`? Is someone/someprogram really `ssh`-ing into your machine every minute from the machine?

Comment: What are the close-votes about? I edited my question to clarify the problem

Comment: Only some mysterious "external" access, or a number of specific ones?

Comment: @0xC0000022L: I see, there seemed to be something missing at the end of my question. I hope now it is clearer

Comment: @rubo77: quite the opposite. Before I had assumed this was about `sshd` but you mentioned `cron` as a counter-example. Now after the latest edit you say effectively you want no emails about `sshd` *or* `cron`?! I am wondering, because I am contemplating to answer, but the question, to me, is still unclear.

Comment: I want to find out, if someone was able to get hold of  password or ssh-key to any of the users on my server and logs in via ssh with that password or ssh-key. I also want to get notified if any person accesses my server.

Comment: Note that you're doing it wrong: if the user pressed Ctrl+C fast enough then `/etc/profile` will be skipped. `pam_exec` is ok because that happens before the actual login. But really what you should look into is log monitoring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me the question is still unclear, so I try to answer the question contained in the first paragraph. How to log SSH logins?

I will also limit my answer to all *nix systems with PAM support. This is a relevant point, because you do not limit the scope of your question by giving a particular OS.

---

Okay, here's what I used in the past: `sshrc`. If you add a file named that in `/etc/ssh` (location may vary!), it will be executed by *interactive* (i.e. with shell) SSH connections.

Downside here is that you won't get informed about the stuff that is also relevant, such as SFTP (`sftp-internal` subsystem) connections.

However, we have an inroute here.

We can use PAM with `pam_exec.so` to our advantage and limit its effect to SSH by adding this to `/etc/pam.d/sshd` (for me it's the last non-comment line):

```
session    optional     pam_exec.so stdout /etc/your_email_script.sh
```

This will ensure that the script gets run as a privileged user (relevant if you prefer to call the sendmail binary to send off the mail) and that there is hardly anything the user can do to avoid this script being run. You can effectively limit access to that script to only `root`.

The part with `optional` you should adjust if needed. Relevant reading: `man pam_exec`, `man pam.conf`, `man pam.d`.

You may also want to play with how early on you want to execute your script.

---

What you see to miss is. You have so many other ways of locking down the server. For starters: don't allow passwords. Stick to key-only authentication. Make sure that people with only SFTP access do not have additional access:

```
Match group sftponly
        ChrootDirectory /home
        X11Forwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        PasswordAuthentication no
```

will let members of group `sftponly` only use SFTP and no port forwarding etc, and limit the scope to `/home` (file/folder permissions do the rest).

```
AllowGroups ssh-users
```

will *only* let members of a group `ssh-users` even log on via SSH. That is, you can limit SSH logon to a subset of your user base.

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

should be set and relevant users be made sudoers instead.

```
PasswordAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

should ensure that password over which you have limited control cannot be used to log on.

```
AuthorizedKeysFile     /some/protected/folder/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

can ensure that users aren't allowed to manage their `authorized_keys` file, but requires you to do it on their behalf.

Comment: I tried a lot now with `pam_exec.so` but I always get notified that the user `root` logged in, instead of my username. I used the script in my question. I tried the option `seteuid` and `quiet` but still, always it sais it was root

Comment: @rubo77: Wait wait wait ... you did read the friendly manual of `pam_exec`, didn't you? Hint the following variables are available to the program run by `pam_exec`: `PAM_RHOST`, `PAM_RUSER`, `PAM_SERVICE`, `PAM_TTY`, `PAM_USER` and `PAM_TYPE`.

Comment: So I can rewrite the script like this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126573/20661

Comment: @rubo77: that looks about right.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! $(whoami) == root ] ; then
echo "Login on $(hostname) at $(date +%Y-%m-%d +%H:%M)"
echo "User: "$(whoami)
echo
id
echo
finger
fi
```

Comment: As a workaround, this would work, but only, if you have root login disabled in your ssh config, otherwise, you would miss mails on a real root login

Comment: sorry, for that. I just want to help

Comment: It is a nice workaround, until i Find a solution to really track the real logins and send an email only then

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by (carefully) editing `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and adding the `pam_exec` module into the stack. This module can be used to call an external program - such as your script - when someone has successfully started an ssh session.

Let me know if you need "how to" instructions and I'll update my answer to include them for a Debian-based system. (Other distributions have slightly different PAM stacks, so you would have to interpret my instructions rather than follow them blindly.)

Comment: set into `/etc/pam.d/sshd` following `session optional pam_exec.so seteuid /home/pi/bin/my_login_notify.sh` but like to have the hostname of the machine who logged in is it possible?

Comment: found it here https://askubuntu.com/questions/179889/how-do-i-set-up-an-email-alert-when-a-ssh-login-is-successful