# Run custom script after logging in, before the banner is shown with ssh

Tags: ssh, openssh

I am running  `OpenSSH_7.6p1` in `Ubuntu 20.4`. I want to run a specific script (`/usr/local/bin/script.sh`) just after logging into SSH. And this script should be run even **before** showing the ssh banner.

The script I am running after the password is specified performs some functions that are responsible for the process of 2 Factor Authentication. So its important that the login banner and the shell access it given after 2FA is verified.

For example, if I want log in as "test" user. I will use `ssh test@localhost` and then right after I specify my password, that script should run, and then if the script executes successfully without any errors, the banner should be displayed and let me access the system shell.

I tried to achieve this with the answers from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/355029/how-to-automatically-run-commands-on-ssh-login/355066) post, but in all of them, the script I specify is executed after the banner is specified.

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. Why must it be before the banner is displayed? What would go wrong if it wasn't? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH Login Alert Using pam\_exec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126566/ssh-login-alert-using-pam-exec)

Comment: The script I am running after the password is specified performs some functions that are responsible for the process of 2 Factor Authentication. So its important that the login banner and the shell access it given after 2FA is verified. @WouterVerhelst

Comment: Please do not add information in the comments. Instead, add it to your question where it can easily be seen

Comment: I think if you want 2FA with SSH, you'll have to configure it *in* SSH, not "after" it.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you state that you are trying to implement 2FA.

This is better implemented as a PAM module, which runs as part of the authentication system (either before or after the password is entered, depending on your configuration).

An example PAM module that implements 2FA can be found at https://cern-cert.github.io/pam_2fa/

Disclaimer: I haven't tried it out myself.

Comment: I tired using PAM and it works as it should (it runs before the login banner), but it is run in background. My script has some information to be displayed to the terminal as well.