# Run command on SSH server whenever a user connects, even if just for tunneling

Tags: ssh, openssh, openbsd

I'd like to, as the administrator of an OpenBSD ssh jumphost used by multiple people, run a specific command any time any user connects via SSH, even if just for tunneling.

Is this possible?

I've tried using `ForceCommand` and `/etc/sshrc` but these seem only to apply when the user has an interactive session and not otherwise.

Because I'm running OpenBSD, nothing PAM-based will work unfortunately, i.e. [This answer on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7391)

The script just runs `sendmail` using the `whoami` and `$SSH_CONNECTION` to inform me of who logged in and from where.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

EMAIL=alerts@example.com

sendmail -F alerts -f $EMAIL root << EOF
Subject: New Login For $1
Message-ID: <$(date +%s)@$(hostname)>
X-Mailer: OpenSMTPD
Content-Type: text/plain

There has been a new login for $1 on $SSH_CONNECTION
EOF
```

Comment: What is this command's purpose, what does it do, what environment does it require? (And, I assume OpenBSD's sshd does not use PAM?)

Comment: Please add the OS specification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can monitor `/var/log/authlog` and use `awk` to send you a message whenever a specific line matches:

```
tail -f /var/log/authlog | awk '/Accepted pubkey/ { system("mail -s " $0 " admin@example.com << EOF\nEOF") }'
```

You can of course replace `/Accepted pubkey/` with some other pattern that fits your case.  I chose to send empty emails with the log line as a subject, for easier reading on the MUA, but you might prefer something like

```
system("mail -s New\\ Login admin@example.com << EOF\n" $0 "\nEOF")
```

Comment: This seems like exactly what I want! Will this work when the log rotates or will it need to be restarted?

Comment: Looks like my version of OpenSSH (8.0) uses "Accepted publickey" not "Accepted pubkey"

Comment: I hadn't thought of log rotation. I'm guessing it needs restarting, since `newsyslog` will create a new empty file, with a different inode, and the original inode will be gone.